# Why does PHP not find my class within the namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, php-5.5

I basically have the following directory structure

- MiniCrawler

  - Scripts/

    - htmlCrawler.php
  - index.php

> This is the index.php

```
use Scripts\htmlCrawler;

class Main
{
    public function init()
    {
        $htmlCrawler = new htmlCrawler();
        $htmlCrawler->sayHello();
    }
}

$main = new Main();
$main->init();
```

> And this is the /Scripts/htmlCrawler.php

```
namespace Scripts;

    class htmlCrawler
    {
        public function sayHello()
        {
            return 'sfs';
        }
    }
```

The code throws the following error

> Fatal error: Class 'Scripts\htmlCrawler' not found in
>   /mnt/htdocs/Spielwiese/MiniCrawler/index.php on line 9

Comment: Do you include `/Scripts/htmlCrawler.php` anywhere in your `index.php` file?

Comment: @AntoineB It works if I use include('Scripts/htmlCrawler.php'); but wouldn't that defeat the purpose of the use statement?, for example Symfony classes only use the 'use' statement without including the files inside of eachother

Comment: I detailed everything  in my answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to include the file `/Scripts/htmlCrawler.php` in your `index.php` file.

```
require_once "Scripts/htmlCrawler.php";

use Scripts\htmlCrawler;

class Main
{
    public function init()
    {
        $htmlCrawler = new htmlCrawler();
        $htmlCrawler->sayHello();
    }
}

$main = new Main();
$main->init();
```

Your index file cannot find the definition of the `htmlCrawler` file if you never provide the file defining this class, and the use of namespaces doesn't automatically include the required classes.

The reason why frameworks don't require you to include manually the file and you can simply add the `use` statement is because they're handling the inclusion of required classes for the developer. Most of the frameworks are using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to handle the automatic inclusion of the files.

You can obtain a somewhat similar functionality using [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Comment: Could also suggest `composer` to take care of the autoloading